# Series de Fibonacci en C++

Tags: c++, fibonacci

Estoy tratando de hacer un programa que me muestre la serie de Fibonacci, sin embargo no salen los valores correctos.
El programa, al principio te pregunta cuántos elementos se muestren en pantalla. Yo escribí 5, por lo que el programa debe mostrarme 1,1,2,3,5, pero me muestra 1,2,3,5 y 8. Incluso busqué tutoriales para ver en qué estaba fallando y me sigue saliendo ese error. Adjunto código.

```
/* Series de Fibonacci */
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int n,x=0,y=1,z=1;

    cout<<"Escribe el número de elementos ";cin>>n;

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){

        z=x+y;

        cout<<z<<" ";
        x=y; 
        y=z;  
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: o sea solo falta un 1? Por qué no lo imprimes?

Answer (score 1):

Los elementos están bien. Solo que se está comenzando a imprimir por el segundo.

Puedes solucionarlo iniciando `y = 0`.

También puedes imprimir el valor antes de hacer cualquier cambio así:

```
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    cout<<z<<" ";
    z=x+y;
    x=y; 
    y=z;  
}
```

O incluso imprimir el valor que te falta antes:

```
cout << "1 ";
for (...)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: gracias, la segunda opción me funcionó